# How to find the increment value over the time series and plot?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, diff

I have some data like ...

```
2020/2/24,1
2020/2/25,1 
2020/2/26,1 
2020/2/27,3 
2020/2/28,4
2020/2/29,5
2020/3/1,5
2020/3/2,6
2020/3/3,6
2020/3/4,6
2020/3/5,6
2020/3/6,6
2020/3/7,6
2020/3/8,6
2020/3/9,7
2020/3/10,9
2020/3/11,12
2020/3/12,15
2020/3/13,19
2020/3/14,21
2020/3/15,22
2020/3/16,24
2020/4/1,57
2020/4/2,60
2020/4/3,63
2020/4/4,69
2020/4/5,70
2020/4/6,73
2020/4/7,80
2020/4/8,81
```

The first column is “Date” and the second column is “death number”. The second column is not death per day, its a cumulative number. Here are my questions

#### 1. How to find death number per day?

I used this code

```
data['inc_death'] = data['death number'].diff()
```

It gives me zero for the top row, but it's not zero, it is One.

#### 2. If I want to plot 3 lines, one for each month, how can I do that?(X-axis:month Y-axis:death number)

because I have data for some days of the month. Also, the number of days in months is not equal as well. My real data is 16days for Feb.,31 days for March, 30 days for April, 8 days for May

Thank you

[image]
edited codes:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("死者数.csv")
#for daily count, given cumulative count
['Daily_Count'] = data['死亡者数'].diff()
data['Daily_Count'][0] = data['死亡者数'][0]
data['Daily_Count']
# #for plotting
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['日付'])
data['year'] = data['datetime'].dt.year
data['months'] = data['datetime'].dt.month
data['day'] = data['datetime'].dt.day
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(data, x="day", y="Daily_Count", color="months", title='死者数', render_mode="svg")
# fig = px.area(data,  x="day", y="Daily_Count", color="months")

fig.show()
```

Comment: if `1` is your initial value, the diff to previous is 0 *because* it's your initial value. otherwise, you'll have to prepend another value to use as initial.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will get the daily count as well create plot as required

```
#for daily count, given cumulative count
df['Daily_Count'] = df['Count'].diff()
df['Daily_Count'][0] = df['Count'][0]

#for plotting
df['months'] = df['Date'].str.slice(3,5)
df['day'] = df['Date'].str.slice(0,2)
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df, x="day", y="Daily_Count", color="months")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I never used plotly before, very cool tool. Thank You. Is there any way to add an annotation to the graph( I found for plotly.graph_objects as go but couldn't plot my data properly). I added my graph, and as you can my Aug. data has still small numbers but it is important and I need to somehow make it noticeable. I edit my initial question.